# Allow access from subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm making a new version of my website on a subdomain of my main site. The url of my main site is http://chirotremelo.be and my subdomain is http://v2.chirotremelo.be . My server setup is the `public_html` folder with within the 'old' version of the website, along with folders with images. There is also a `v2` folder in this folder, containing my new version which also uses images from the standard website.

I develop my new version on my local machine, also having the `v2` folder inside the main site. This is done so I can easily update it.

Now, because my `v2` loads resources from the `v2` version as well as the main site version, I set the `<base>` to `http://chirotremelo.be/`. To include files from the `v2` folder I simply add `v2/` in front of a certain url.

Locally this works nicely, but on my live version it doesn't seem to load eg `http://chirotremelo.be/v2/newSite.css`. The error shown is:

```
Imported resource from origin 'http://chirotremelo.be' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://v2.chirotremelo.be' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have searched around for this but can't seem to find any solutions right away. I think it might have something to do with my `.htaccess` file, so here it is included:

```
php_value date.timezone Europe/Brussels

<FilesMatch ".php$">
AddHandler x-httpd-php54 .php
</FilesMatch>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?chirotremelo\.be/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www.chirotremelo.be [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://chirotremelo.be/ [last,redirect=301]
```

I know this might not be a lot to go on but I've never worked with subdomains before. I have successfully used `http://v2.chirotremelo.be/newSite.css`, but it kind of needs to be with a base of the non-subdomain to load the content that is only available on the main site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem called Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing (or `CORS` in short). You will find many questions here facing the problem, especially for asynchronous JavaScript requests.

It is some kind of browser related issue; the server will still serve the files requested, but the browser blocks it to prevent that a site will load "bad" content from a "bad" site. You need to send a CORS-Header with your server response to let the browser allow it.

In your case (as this is not a production site), I would advise you the following solution:

You could try to add

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

to your `.htaccess` file. (Note, this needs [`mod_headers`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) in Apache to be enabled, but I guess this is enabled by default).

This is not the *best* solution, especially there might be more elegant ones with redirect rules. But it should work for this special case (testing/beta site).

Comment: This seems to work fine, perfect! Since it is indeed temporary (as long as both sites are live), I'll leave it as is.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I always appreciate that!